# Error: Access Denied on IIS using Google Youtube Data API V3 Oauth service

Tags: google-api, iis-7, youtube-data-api

I have created a web page `(youtubeuploader.aspx)` in `asp.net` to `upload Video to youtube channel` on `button` `click`. 
The video file location say eg:
`'d:\\youtubevdos\\test.3gp'.`

I have `hosted` this web application in `IIS7`.

This page works fine on local machine with proper `Oauth2.0 authentication` and `Video` is uploaded to `youtube` `channel`. **But, it wont work when hosted on web server i mean IIS server**

**It gives error:**

**"Access Denied"** Access to path/directory 'App_Data' is denied.

```
UserCredential credential;
//string googleaccesstoken = Server.MapPath("mygooglestorage");
string googleaccesstoken = "D:\\websites\\mygooglestorage\\";
//using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{

    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(googleaccesstoken)
    );
}
```

I have tried following ways:

- Explicitly setting the `FileDataStore` while authentication i.e specifying file location something to `'D:\websites\myproj\authkey\'` but still same error.
- Created a folder in hosted location as given above and given `access rights` as `'FullControl'` to folder still same error.

**Note:** i am using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`, `Google Youtube API v3`, `OAuth2.0`

Any suggestions?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Give all permissions to app data folder for users - IUSER and Network Service.

Comment: tried with IUSER and Network service but still same issue..:(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new FileDataStore(googleaccesstoken, true)
```

The second parameter is to indicate that fullPath is absolute.